# Proof that $n! > n + 1$, $\forall n > 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, induction

I'm trying to understand the usage of math induction, so I came up with this exercise:

> Show that $n! > n + 1$, $\forall n > 2, n\in\mathbb N$.

So I started with the base case of $n = 3$:

\begin{gather*}
3! > 3 + 1 \\
6 > 4.
\end{gather*}

Considering $k! > k+1$ and $k > 2$, now to prove $(k + 1)! > k+1+1$:

\begin{gather*}
(k+1)! = (k+1)k! = kk! + k! \\
kk! + k! > (k+1)k+k+1.
\end{gather*}
(Changing $k!$ to $k+1$, because of the condition above.)

Since $k > 2$ can I do the following?

$$(k+1)! > (0+1)1 + k + 1.$$

Then

$$(k+1)! > k + 1 + 1.$$

Is this the correct way to prove the statement?

Comment: What you’ve done is really nice, and here’s another way: (k+1)k+k+1=(k+2)k+1>(k+2)k>k+2

Comment: To answer your last question $n!\ge 2n>n+1$ for $n>2$ is probably much simpler... But as an exercise on induction, well why not.

Comment: I'm not following your thinking.  You did all that nice work to get $kk! + k! > (k+1)k + k+1$, but then you never touched it and the you seem to start all over again and state with no justification that $(k+1)! > (0+1)1 + k+1$.  Are trying to combine your previous work? Do you mean to show that it was actually $(k+1)k + k+1$ that was actually larger than $(0+1)1 + k+1$?  [If so, then yes.. as $k> 2 > 0$ then $k+1> (0+1)$ and $k > 1$ and $k+1 = k+1$ so $(k+1)k + k+1 > (0+1)1 + k+1$.]

Comment: Again it is probably easy to just say $(k+1)! = (k+1)k! > (k+1)(k+1)=k(k+1) + (k+1)> 1+(k+1)$....  As $k!$ increases bu multiplying by $k+1$ which is *so* much more growth then $k+1$ which only increases by adding $1$ you can pretty much close your eyes, swing a dead cat, and be practically assured you will hit the planet earth somehow.  Almost any approach will work with *huge* amount of leeway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> \begin{gather*}
> (k+1)! = (k+1)k! = kk! + k! \\
> kk! + k! > (k+1)k+k+1.
> \end{gather*}

Start from here, **your goal** is to show $(k+1)!>(k+1)+1$

Using your assumption $k!>k+1$, So you get:

$$(k+1)!=(k+1)\cdot k!>(k+1)\cdot (k+1)$$

Now, you need to show (which is very simple): $$(k+1)\cdot (k+1)>(k+1)+1$$
Then you are done for the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Per your question, yes you can. But you can just say: $k>2 \implies (k+1)k > 1\implies (k+1)k+k+1> 1+(k+1)\implies (k+1)! > (k+1)+1$.